# Reusable ASP.NET MVC components in dll like ASP.NET WebControls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll

I have several websites and these website share several components. It was quite easy with classic ASP.NET WebControls ascx. I created several such controls, put into one dll library and I reference these libraries from these websites via namespace.elements runat=server...

But I don't know how to do it after I have upgraded to ASP.NET MVC. I can put model and cotroller class into dll.

But how should I put and reuse Views into dll?

I suppose that Views are not compiled into dll, if I can change the View without recompiling the dll.

EDITS:
I would prefer some standard solution over third party. The last solution for me is to use StringBuilder instead of ViewEngine.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using [Razor Generator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator) for several years to store reusable MVC views and helpers in separate .dll.

**Razor Generator** "is a Custom Tool for Visual Studio that allows processing Razor files at design time instead of runtime, allowing them to be built into an assembly for simpler reuse and distribution."

> **Installation instructions**
>
> It’s on the VS extension gallery, so install
>   it from there. It’s called [“Razor Generator”](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f6ec6ff-e89b-4c47-8e79-d2d68df894ec) (not to be confused with
>   “Razor Single File Generator for MVC”).

It is quite simple to use:

> **Usage in an MVC app**
>
> 1. Install the 'RazorGenerator.Mvc' package, which registers a special
>      view engine
> 2. Go to an MVC Razor view's property and set the Custom tool to RazorGenerator
> 3. Optionally specify a value for Custom Tool Namespace to specify a namespace for the generated file. The project namespace is used by
>      default.
> 4. Optionally specify one of the generators in the first line of your Razor file. A generator declaration line looks like this: @*
>      Generator: MvcHelper *@ . If you don't specify this, a generator is
>      picked based on convention (e.g. files under Views are treated as
>      MvcViews)
> 5. You'll see a generated .cs file under the .cshtml file, which will be used at runtime instead of the .cshtml file
> 6. You can also go to the nuget Package Manager Console and run 'Enable-RazorGenerator' to enable the Custom Tool on all the views.
> 7. And to cause all the views to be regenerated, go to the nuget Package Manager Console and run 'Redo-RazorGenerator'. This is
>      useful when you update the generator package and it needs to
>      generate different code.

MVC project should be chosen for class library in order to support intellisense and other useful features.

> **Usage in a View Library**
>
> If you need to create a separate library for your precompiled MVC
>   views,  the best approach is to actually create an MVC project for
>   that library,  instead of a library project. You'll never actually run
>   it as an Mvc app,  but the fact that it comes with the right set of
>   config files allows  intellisense and other things to work a lot
>   better than in a library project.
>
> You can then add a reference to that 'MVC View project' from your real
>   MVC app.
>
> And note that you need to install the '[RazorGenerator.Mvc](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/)' package 
>   into the library, not the main MVC app.

[Programming ASP.NET MVC 4](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=0jyfL7CzXvgC) written by Jess Chadwick tells that

> In the ASP.NET Web Forms world, you can achieve this by creating user
>   controls or custom controls that can be compiled into standalone
>   assemblies. These assemblies can be distributed across projects,
>   thereby enabling their reuse across projects.
>
> The Web Forms view
>   engine offers the **ViewUserControl** class, which can be leveraged to
>   create such components for the MVC framework. The Razor view engine in
>   ASP.NET MVC, however, does not offer any such method out of the box.

and suggests using [Razor Single File Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f28290ce-d987-4f91-b034-707031e10ce6) visual studio extension, another one but the similar to [Razor Generator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator) approach.

Comment: Yes, Razor Generator is a good way. If you'll need more information, I can recommend you Programming ASP.NET MVC 4 written by Jess Chadwick. There is whole Chapter 15 - Reusable UI Components about this.

Comment: Thanks, I've read an overview of this book and I think I am about to start reading it.

Comment: Hmm Razor Generator is interesting solution, but is seems quite complicated for such simple task. I would prefer some more standard way without any third party dependency. The third party dependency is always a risk for me. I mean support of next visual studio, next .NET version. How it will work with msbuild process? And how about Microsoft, do they intend to use third party extension? Do they designed non reusable UI? I will study the provided links and I will respond later.

Comment: I hope MVC5 adopt this feature from any open source project. Programming ASP.NET MVC 4 written by Jess Chadwick tells that _"The Razor view engine in ASP.NET MVC, however, does not offer any such method out of the box."_

Comment: You can easily create controllers in a dll that service ChildActions for partial views etc and your model classes in the dll with no problem.

So for the actual cshtml file market, you can store them in the same dll as an embeded resource.  Then just create a VirtualPathProvider that uses Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream to return your views.  Then you can serve up views from the dll.

Comment: I actually designed my virtual path provider so that I can configure an app setting that tells it that cshtml files in X Folder should override the ones in the dll.  So if I want to customize one for a specific project, I just create a cshtml file in the folder and it overrides it.